# good book on Object-oriented analysis and modeling?

Tags: oop, architecture, modeling

There are some mentioned in here but not directly so Questions should be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)

There is a free version as well at http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly

Comment: It's not really free, it requires registration.

Comment: I think it is. Registration to infoq.com is free.